# How to optimise INSERT into link table

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

Can anyone recommend a better SQL statement or approach so that I can `INSERT INTO` a link table faster? My current approach slows down as the tables get larger and my link table `INSERT` query is the problem.

I have two tables joined by a link table. The schema is below:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
field1 VARCHAR(40))

CREATE TABLE table2
(id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
field1 VARCHAR(100),
field2 INT,
field3 VARCHAR(40))

CREATE TABLE linkTable
(id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
field1 INT REFERENCES table1(id),
field2 INT REFERENCES table2(id))
```

Because I am trying to **batch inserts**, I am currently checking that I am not adding duplicate values in the link table with this long query:

```
INSERT INTO linktable(field1,field2)
SELECT table1Id, table2Id FROM
(SELECT table1.id table1Id, table2.id table2Id FROM table1,table2
WHERE table1.name=? AND table2.name=?) tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT linktable.field1 FROM linktable tmp1 WHERE
tmp1.field1=tmp.table1id AND tmp1.field2=tmp.table2id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using java to insert it you can use a ResultSet to check the count of something in a column and then insert if that count is equal to zero like so.

```
ResultSet = Statement.executeQuery ("Select count     (column_name) From table_name Where column_name = 'whatever';

While (rs.next ()){
 Int count = rs.getInt (count (column_name);

 If (count == 0){
         Statement2.executeUpdate ("INSERT INTO......")

  } 


   }
```